# chef - how to get path of cookbook in a recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

From default.rb, I want to access the relative path of the cookbook.

I tried doing:

```
print "cookbook path: " + run_context.cookbook_collection[cookbook_name].root_dir
```

but I get

```
TypeError
---------
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

I tried replacing cookbook_name with my cookbook name, but get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Feels weird what you're doing. What's your actual goal?

Comment: Use the relative path of the chef cookbook to execute a powershell script regardless of where chef is located on the computer

Comment: Not how Chef works..

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported API, we do not offer it in an official capacity. Any use of such APIs is at your own risk and *will* break in the future so you should be comfortable enough with reading the code to find things yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me: `Chef::Config[:cookbook_path]`